# Проблемы при установке VirtualBox на Ubuntu 18.04.1 lts

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

После установки virtualbox и команды

```
$ virtualbox
```

появляется предупреждение

> WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no
>   module available for the current kernel (4.13.0-36-generic) or it
>   failed to load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by
>   sudo /sbin/vboxconfig You will not be able to start VMs until this
>   problem is fixed.

Выполняю команду

```
 $ sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

Ответ:

> vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services. vboxdrv.sh: Starting
>   VirtualBox services. vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
>   This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules. Please
>   install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
>   for adding new hardware support to the system. The distribution
>   packages containing the headers are probably:
>       linux-headers-generic linux-headers-4.13.0-36-generic This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules. Please install the
>   Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel for adding new
>   hardware support to the system. The distribution packages containing
>   the headers are probably:
>       linux-headers-generic linux-headers-4.13.0-36-generic
>
> There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up
>   process, run   /sbin/vboxconfig as root.

Выполняю команду:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Ответ:

> Чтение списков пакетов… Готово Построение дерева зависимостей
>   Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово У**же установлен пакет
>   linux-headers-generic самой новой версии (4.15.0.43.45)**. Обновлено 0
>   пакетов, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов,
>   и 0 пакетов не обновлено.

Выполняю команду:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.13.0-36-generic
```

Ответ:

> Чтение списков пакетов… Готово Построение дерева зависимостей
>   Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово Пакет
>   linux-headers-4.13.0-36-generic недоступен, но упомянут в списке
>   зависимостей другого пакета. Это может означать, что пакет
>   отсутствует, устарел, или доступен из источников, не упомянутых в
>   sources.list
>
> E: Для пакета «linux-headers-4.13.0-36-generic» не найден кандидат на
>   установку

В чем проблема?

Comment: Какая версия vb?

Comment: Попробуйте удалить текущую и установить вот так https://www.onlineinterviewquestions.com/blog/installing-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts/

Comment: А откуда ты её взял?